# maven: how to clean the old snapshot in local repo?

Tags: maven, snapshot

I used a snapshot jar in my pom.xml which developed by another team.After a period of time, I found a lots of snapshot jar with timestamp in my local repo like bellows:

base-0.0.1-20190924.065706-10.jar
base-0.0.1-20190925.002128-11.jar
base-0.0.1-20191107.012927-66.jar
base-0.0.1-20191108.002149-68.jar

I knew I can remove them manually, but I think there must be a way to clear them automatically？
Dose anybody know it ?

Comment: Those are not snapshots! You might want to read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901378/what-exactly-is-a-maven-snapshot-and-why-do-we-need-it and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19310650/how-to-clean-old-dependencies-from-maven-repositories

Comment: @JFMeier Could you give me some kind of link to this. The only thing that I can find on snapshots, as far as Maven understands them, is "-SNAPSHOT" in the name convention.

Comment: I don't have a docs about this, but if you look into any Nexus or Artifactory and look at the files that were deployed as `1.2.3-SNAPSHOT`, you see that they are saved in the form `1.2.3-{sometimestamp}-{somenumber}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mvn dependency:purge-local-repository` might help. Take a look at the section about including specific groupId's or artifactId's.

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/purging-local-repository.html

Comment: Thanks Jim.  It's work. After I used it, only one snapshot kept.  Thank you very much.